# How to faster iterate over a Python numpy.ndarray with 2 dimensions

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

So, i simply want to make this faster:

```
for x in range(matrix.shape[0]):
        for y in range(matrix.shape[1]):
            if matrix[x][y] == 2 or matrix[x][y] == 3 or matrix[x][y] == 4 or matrix[x][y] == 5 or matrix[x][y] == 6:
                if x not in heights:
                    heights.append(x)
```

Simply iterate over a 2x2 matrix (usually round 18x18 or 22x22) and check it's x. But its kinda slow, i wonder which is the fastest way to do this.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a numpy based approach, you can do:

```
np.flatnonzero(((a>=2) & (a<=6)).any(1))
# array([1, 2, 6], dtype=int64)
```

---

Where:

```
a = np.random.randint(0,30,(7,7))

print(a)

array([[25, 27, 28, 21, 18,  7, 26],
       [ 2, 18, 21, 13, 27, 26,  2],
       [23, 27, 18,  7,  4,  6, 13],
       [25, 20, 19, 15,  8, 22,  0],
       [27, 23, 18, 22, 25, 17, 15],
       [19, 12, 12,  9, 29, 23, 21],
       [16, 27, 22, 23,  8,  3, 11]])
```

---

Timings on a larger array:

```
a = np.random.randint(0,30, (1000,1000))

%%timeit
heights=[]
for x in range(a.shape[0]):
        for y in range(a.shape[1]):
            if a[x][y] == 2 or a[x][y] == 3 or a[x][y] == 4 or a[x][y] == 5 or a[x][y] == 6:
                if x not in heights:
                    heights.append(x)
# 3.17 s ± 59.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
yatu = np.flatnonzero(((a>=2) & (a<=6)).any(1))
# 965 µs ± 11.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

np.allclose(yatu, heights)
# true
```

Vectorizing with numpy yields to roughly a `3200x` speedup

Comment: Still somewhat confused, would you mind to apply that to my problem so i can see how this would work? Thank you!

Comment: Well you have not shared sample data. I've checked and this is doing exactly the same as your code. `heights` was [1,2,6] for this example array `a` @LaioZatt

Comment: I see. I did manage to make it work, but it doesnt seem faster, atleast doing:`findHeightsTime = time.time()

heights = numpy.flatnonzero(((matrix>=2) & (matrix<=6)).any(1))

heights = heights[::-1]

print("findHeightsTime : " + str(time.time() - findHeightsTime))`
Maybe im doing something wrong? Thanks again =)

Comment: Sure it does. You need to check on larger samples. Added timings @LaioZatt

Comment: I didnt manage to get that '%%timeit' working, but i tried it with time.timeit() and this code did around 40x faster than the one i was using. Any reason for that difference in tests?
Im doing:
setup = '''
import numpy
    '''
    code = '''
heights = numpy.flatnonzero(((matrix>=2) & (matrix<=6)).any(1))
    '''
    timea = timeit.timeit(stmt=code, setup=setup, number=10000, globals={'matrix' : globals().get('matrix'), 'heights' : globals().get('heights')})

Only changing the code part to mine and back. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to find if 2, 3, 4, 5 or 6 appear in the matrix.

You can use `np.isin()` to create a matrix of true/false values, then use that as an indexer:

```
>>> arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,4,0]).reshape(2,3)
>>> arr[np.isin(arr, [2,3,4,5,6])]
array([2, 3, 4, 4])
```

Optionally, turn that into a plain Python `set()` for faster `in` lookups and no duplicates.

To get the positions in the array where those numbers appear, use `argwhere`:

```
>>> np.argwhere(np.isin(arr, [2,3,4,5,6]))
array([[0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1]])
```

Comment: I want to get the X position of that 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6, if it appears in the matrix. Your solution would still work? Would you mind to apply that to my problem? Im a Python newbie =P. Thank you!