# Fastest iteration over 2 dimensions in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

Which is the fastest way to iterate over a 2 dimension array in python? Considering i always need x and y indexes.

Example, i have this code that tries to 'match' 3 of the same number in a matrix, if they are the numbers 2, 3, 4, 5 or 6:

```
for x in range(matrix.shape[0]):
    for y in range(matrix.shape[1]):
        if matrix[x][y] == 2 or matrix[x][y] == 3 or matrix[x][y] == 4 or matrix[x][y] == 5 or matrix[x][y] == 6: ## if i find one of the numbers i need
            fuseNumber = matrix[x][y] ## lets get that number
            if matrix[x+1][y] == fuseNumber: ## if we find another of that to the bottom of the initial one, we should try to find a third one
                if matrix[x-1][y] == fuseNumber: ## if we find another one at the top from the initial one
                    matrix[x][y] = 0
                    matrix[x+1][y] = 0
                    matrix[x-1][y] = 0
                    ...
```

The code would keep going with some ifs just like this one, to make sure it tests all possible combinations, but that doesnt rly matter.
I tried changing this for:

```
it = numpy.nditer(matrix, flags=['multi_index'])
while not it.finished:
    x = it.multi_index[0]
    y = it.multi_index[1]
    if matrix[x][y] == 2 or matrix[x][y] == 3 or matrix[x][y] == 4 or matrix[x][y] == 5 or matrix[x][y] == 6:
        fuseNumber = matrix[x][y] ## lets get that fuse number, whichever it may be!
        if matrix[x+1][y] == fuseNumber: ## if we find another of that to the bottom of the initial one, we should try to find a third one
            if matrix[x-1][y] == fuseNumber: ## if we find another one at the top from the initial one  ///////  center bottom top
                matrix[x][y] = 0
                matrix[x+1][y] = 0
                matrix[x-1][y] = 0
                ...
it.iternext()
```

But using timeit.timeit() it showed me the second code is actually slower. Despite these two examples, how would you write the same code, but with maximum performance?

Thank you!

Comment: `nditer` is not a faster iterator, at least not when used at the Python level.  It only helps if used in compiled code.  There isn't a faster way to iterate of an array in Python code.  Iterating on a list is faster.  To get the best `numpy` speed you should use the fast compiled `numpy` methods, not iteration.

Comment: What was wrong with answers to your previous question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60993647/how-to-faster-iterate-over-a-python-numpy-ndarray-with-2-dimensions.  I'm tempted to tag this as duplicate.

Comment: @hpaulj nothing, really, its just a different question since now i need to control indexes more, its actually for another method but i admit the question looks like the same hhaha

Answer (score 0):

**Rather than search using your double for loop:**

```
for x in range(matrix.shape[0]):
    for y in range(matrix.shape[1]):
        if matrix[x][y] == 2 or matrix[x][y] == 3 or matrix[x][y] == 4 or matrix[x][y] == 5 or matrix[x][y] == 6: ## if i find one of the numbers i need
            fuseNumber = matrix[x][y] ## lets get that fuse number,
         ...
```

**You can search using where** [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869173/numpy-find-index-of-the-elements-within-range?noredirect=1)

This allows looping only over the x, y values in the desired range.

```
for x, y in zip(*np.where(np.logical_and(matrix>=2, matrix<=6))):
    fuseNumber = matrix[x][y] ## lets get that fuse number,
         ...
```

**Test**

Test that the two methods create the same x,y pairs

```
# Random matrix (5, 10) with numbers between 0 & 10
matrix = np.random.randint(0, 10,  size=(5, 10))

# OP method
set_for = set()
for x in range(matrix.shape[0]):
    for y in range(matrix.shape[1]):
      if 2 <= matrix[x][y] <= 6:
        set_for.add((x, y))

# Method using where
set_numpy = set((x, y) for x, y in zip(*np.where(np.logical_and(matrix>=2, matrix<=6))))

# Result
print(set_for == set_numpy)
```

*Output*

```
True
```

Comment: I did this, and its indeed faster, tho it doesnt do the same thing, my program kinda stopped doing what it should, i didnt realize what is the problem yet but will look into that tomorrow. Do you have any insight? Maybe i should do 'for y, x' instead of 'for x, y' ?
Thanks!

Comment: @LaioZatt--x, y should correspond to row, column pairs as you have.  Perhaps you can try placing the x, y pairs this method finds into a set to compare to the x, y pairs the double for loop method finds.  Then check to see if the two sets are equal.

Comment: @LaioZatt--added a simple test (see update) and the new method produces the same x, y pairs as the original.

Comment: Thank you, though im a still a bit confused on how to apply this line to my problem. Where i use it like 
`fuseNumber = matrix[x][y] ## lets get that number
 if matrix[x+1][y] == fuseNumber: ## if we find another of that to the bottom of the 
initial one, we should try to find a third one
 if matrix[x-1][y] == fuseNumber: ## if we find another one at the top from the initial one
 matrix[x][y] = 0
 matrix[x+1][y] = 0
 matrix[x-1][y] = 0`
How would you use it with that syntax? Im still a newbie =P.
Thanks again

Comment: @LaioZatt--If x, y gets through your two outer loops, then we know that `2 <= matrix[x][y] <= 6`.  So we only need to consider these x, y pairs.  For each other these x, y pairs  you check if `matrix[x+1][y] = matrix[x][y]`and `matrix[x-1][[y] = matrix[x][y]` (you're setting `fusenumber = matrix[x][y]` for the comparison but you can use matrix[x][y] rather than fusenumber. Possible issue is you're not checking if `0 < x < len(matrix[0]) - 1]`.  That needs to be checked since if `x = 0`, then `matrix[x-1] would be an index out of range error.  Similar error if 'x >= len(matrix[0]) -1`.